# Infinite console log in react js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have made two simple straight forward component is React, used a open source API to test API integration. React is showing this weird behavior of infinite console logs. I don't understand the issue. I'm using the fetch function for making API calls and functional component.

App component:

```js
function App() {

 const [characters, setCharac] = useState([])

  const URL = "https://swapi.dev/api/";

   fetch(URL + "people").then(response => response.json().then(data => {
     setCharac(data.results)
     console.log('Test');
   }))

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {characters.map(charac => {
        return <Character {...charac} />
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Character component:

```js
const Character = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div key={props.name}>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <p>{props.height}</p>
    </div>
  );

}
```

`console.log('Test');` in App component and `console.log(props);` in Character component are being executed infinitely.

This is the render method

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Your `fetch` call has a "side effect" - it changes some state when the call finishes. Because of this, you shouldn't have this happen on its own, it should be run from within a [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). The [beta docs](https://beta-reactjs-org-git-effects-fbopensource.vercel.app/learn/synchronizing-with-effects) also have info on this hook.

Comment: @Ahmed Javed Every time you do "setCharac" you component will go through re-render and again fetch will be called again.

Comment: even if I do it using useEffect it shows the same behavior.

Comment: use another function to setState inside `useEffect`. Do not use setState directly inside the `useEffect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your components are rendering multiple times because your state is changed every time you fetch data (because of `setState`).

Try creating a function `fetchData()`. Make this function `async` as well to wait for data to be retrieved.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
   const result = await fetch(URL + "people").then(response => response.json().then(data => {
    setCharac(data.results)
    console.log('Test');
    return data;
   }));
   return result;
}
```

and then use it inside `useEffect` (Read more about useEffects: [React hooks: What/Why `useEffect`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051465/react-hooks-what-why-useeffect))

```
useEffect(() => {
   fetchData();
}, []);
```

Note the usage of `[]` in `useEffect`. The data will be fetched only once when you load the component.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  usage of [] is really weird. I wasn't passing it earlier.

Comment: Happy to help, this explains the `useEffect` behaviour https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62631053/useeffect-being-called-multiple-times

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it in a useEffect

e.g.

```
useEffect(()=>{
fetch(URL + "people").then(response => response.json().then(data => {
     setCharac(data.results)
     console.log('Test');
   }))
},[])
```

otherwise every time the state is set it is firing off the fetch again because a re-render is being triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Because you `fetch` some data, update the state, which causes a re-render, which does another `fetch`, updates the state, which causes another render...etc.

Call your `fetch` function from inside a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) with an empty dependency array so that it only gets called once when the component is initially rendered.

Note 1: you can't immediately log the state after setting it as setting the state is an async process. You can, however, use another `useEffect` to watch for changes in the state, and log its updated value.

Note 2: I've used [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) in this example as the syntax is a little cleaner.

```js
// Fetch the data and set the state
async function getData(endpoint) {
  const json = await fetch(`${endpoint}/people`);
  const data = await response.json();
  setCharac(data.results);
}

// Call `getData` when the component initially renders
useEffect(() => {
  const endpoint = 'https://swapi.dev/api';
  getData(endpoint);
}, []);

// Watch for a change in the character state, and log it
useEffect(() => console.log(characters), [characters]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

const Character = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div key={props.name}>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <p>{props.height}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [characters, setCharac] = useState([]);

  const makeFetch = useCallback(() => {
    const URL = "https://swapi.dev/api/";
    fetch(URL + "people").then((response) =>
      response.json().then((data) => {
        setCharac(data.results);
        console.log("Test");
      })
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    makeFetch();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {characters.map((charac) => {
        return <Character {...charac} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```