# useState Hook react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

in useState hook when the setState is called it will initializes the state with a new value
i have the example of code below :

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { useState } from 'react'

function MyComponent(){
  const [status,setStatus] = useState(0);

  function update_state(){
    setStatus(1);
  }
  update_state();
  return(
    <div>
      <h1 id='hello'>{status}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
const body = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("body"));
body.render(<MyComponent/>);
```

from above code,when the update_state() is called then after that it will initializes the status with a new value but i got this error :

> Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

where is my mistake, cause i thought when i called the update_state the status will be initializes with 1 but instead i got 1 i got and  Uncaught Error

Answer (score 4):

The reason for infinite loop of re-rendering is trying to update the state within the functional component itself. If you want to call `update_state()` as the component renders, you can use useEffect hook in React.

First you have to import the hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

Then inside the functional component call `update_state()` using `useEffect` :

```
useEffect(()=>{
 update_state();
}, []) // <-- This empty array will make the useEffect called only once.
```

For your reference:

[React hooks: What/Why `useEffect`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051465/react-hooks-what-why-useeffect)

https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 1):

When `setStatus` function is called, React re-renders the component and that makes infinite loop.

you need to check `status` in the function to prevent falling in loop.

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { useState } from 'react'

function MyComponent(){
  const [status,setStatus] = useState(0);

  function update_state(){
    if (status === 1) return; // prevent loop

    setStatus(1);
  }
  update_state();
  return(
    <div>
      <h1 id='hello'>{status}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
const body = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("body"));
body.render(<MyComponent/>);
```

Comment: You solution makes sense but, what if you want to use 'status' in any other method inside the component or how would you add reusable logics inside update_state() after making it executable only once?

Comment: I just want to let OP know that when the state changes, re-rendering happens and how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use useeffect hook to render it only once. have a look on the following code

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    function update_state() {
      setStatus(1);
    }
    update_state();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 id="hello">{status}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```